# Listview.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize) expands last column to fill listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, autoresize, column-width

This just started happening in the last week. I'm currently using VS 2012 Professional on Windows 10, coding in VB.NET. I had been successfully using Listview.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize) to resize the columns prior to passing the listview to a printing routine. I took a week off the project and when I ran it again the last column started to occupy the remaining balance of the listview width after calling the method, getting rid of what some call the 'ugly' last empty column. So it now pushes that last column off onto another page due to the increased width. It did not do this before. In that week off I did install the VS 2015 Community edition to evaluate.
Has anyone else noticed this? And if so... solution?

Comment: If you do not show how you print it and what the result of that is, how do you expect anyone of us to help? We're not magicians, you know. Only you know the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

When using Listview.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize) it will work as desired by resizing ALL the Columns to the Width of the Header Text ONLY if the ListView's width is less than the total Column widths.
If the ListView's width is wider than the total Column widths, then the LAST Column will then fill the remaining space, which is what I did not want reflected in my printing routine. I was using those Column widths in my printing routine. The problem was those widths, which changed as the ListView's width changed,  being passed into the printing routine. Not reliable.

My Work-Around: I simple resized the last Column the 'old fashioned' way after calling .AutoResizeColumns.

Also. I didn't feel the need to post any code, as the one, snarky, condescending comment states, as it was a behavioral problem, not a code problem, and would have only clouded the issue. But thanks for the input 'Visual' Vincent. It really added to the solution!